# Подключение GFLW к MinGW

Tags: opengl, clion

Мне нужно подключить `GLFW` и `OpenGL`, что бы использовать в `С++ проекте`. Я использую `CLion + CMake`. Не нашел как подключить OpenGL. Нашел только в официальной документации (http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html) GLFW инструкции по подключению. У меня Windows и MinGW, соответственно выбираю: `With MinGW or Visual C++ on Windows` . 
С английским у меня плохо, а переводчик выдал что-то не понятное. Объясните как подключить.. У меня установлен GLFW в папку C:\Program Files\glfw (64х разрядный) .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования библиотеки нужно:

- Подключить её заголовочные файлы
- Слинковать её с вашим приложением

Для линковки библиотека должна быть в вашей системе. Подозреваю что OpenGL в виде shared библиотеки в windows есть, а GLFW нет.
Тогда её нужно собрать из сорцов или скачать уже собранную, но совместимую с вашим компилятором.

Т.к. вы используете CMake, то подключение заголовочных файлов и линковка описывается в нём.
Примерный вид минимального CMakeLists.txt для этого:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(project_name)
add_executable(myApp "src/main.cpp")

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myApp ${OpenGL_LIBRARIES})

find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myApp ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

`find_package()` выполняет поиск файла `Find<package_name>.cmake` 
 в директориях `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` и исполняет его.
Этот файл должен определить некоторые переменные, в том числе `<package_name>_INCLUDE_DIR` и `<package_name>_LIBRARIES`.
`include_directories()` добавляет директорию в которой будет выполняться поиск заголовочных файлов директивой `#include`.
`target_link_libraries()` линкует указанную библиотеку с вашим таргетом. Можно использовать как для shared так и для static библиотек.

Практически уверен в том что вместе с cmake не идёт find файл для GLFW.
Можете или найти его или создать свой или напрямую прописать пути до его инклюдов и собранной либы. Я предпочитаю Find файлы. Если зависимостей много и они различаются в разных системах, то их можно удобно править независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Хорошо объяснили, но.. Я добавил фото в вопрос. Ошибок нет, а хидер glfw3.h не находит...

Comment: В данном случае путь к заголовкам не должен включать папку GLFW в конце. Конечно можно и включить, но это странно т.к. она явно в include папке, а во вторых у вас в проекте наверняка инклюды заголовков этой либы учитывают наличие этой папки и из-за этого заголовки не находятся. А второе меня смущает отсутствие конкретной библиотеки с которой должно идти связывание. Вероятно на этапе линковки будет ошибка. Должно выглядеть примерно так: `include_directories("C:/Program Files/glfw/include")` `target_link_libraries(Test "C:/Program Files/glfw/lib-mingw-w65/libglfw3.dll")`